# Passing entity connection string dynamically - multiple entities with multiple environment

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have multiple entities in my project. My customer don't want to keep any connection strings in web.config file. So they will create the environmental variable for each entity in octopus and that will create an environment config file in my project. So I need to read this environment variables and pass it to entities.

I cannot use parametarized constructor as it requires a lot of code change. 
Cannot modify the auto generated entity context files.

I already tried with partial class and parametarized constructor.

```
public partial class SitesEntities
    {
        public SitesEntities(string conn)
            : base(GetConnectionString())
        {

        }

        public static string GetConnectionString()
        {
//code
}
}
```

This require a code change while initializing each entity. That is a challenging task for us since we are using this at lot of place

```
 using (SitesEntities entities = new SitesEntities())
{
//code
}
```

Can anyone suggest any alternate solution for this?

Comment: This is why dependency injection is awesome

Answer (score 0):

Dependency injection would be awesome to solve this. But I think the way you already mentioned should work, too (it's ugly, tho):

```
public partial class SitesEntities
{
    public SitesEntities()
        : base(GetConnectionString())
    {
    }

    public static string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("my_env_varible");
    }
}
```

What did I missunderstand if that's not working for you?

Comment: Here the issue is to create default constructor . It will not allow to create one in partial class.
public SitesEntities()
        : base(GetConnectionString())
    {
    }

Comment: I guess that is because the default constructor is already declared in the other part of your partial class? Just change the code there?

Comment: Other class is auto generated class from entity. I don't want modify that file.

Comment: I see. I don't think there's a way to solve this if you a) don't want to change the default constructor or b) don't want to change the calls to `using (SitesEntities entities = new SitesEntities())`.

Comment: Saxx, I also think this is not possible at this point even with dependency injection. The challenge i faced to not modify the entity initialization. I should change it every where. Thanks